# VBA Error '9' subscript Out of Range when copying worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm Currently trying to create a code that will grab all the worksheets from a number of workbooks and paste them into a pre-selected workbook.

So far the code works, but only some of the time, the rest of the time it tells me that the `workbooks("Name").Sheet(i)` subscript out of range. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to the Error

```
If Not UserForm1.filePath = "" Then
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = OpenDatabase(UserForm1.filePath)
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tIO")
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
        While Not rst.EOF
            If Not Filename = rst!Filename Then
                Filename = rst!Filename
                Dim wbSource As Workbook
                Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filename)

                Counter = Counter + 1
                'Loop through all of the worksheets in the Active workbook
                For Each WS In wbSource.Worksheets
                    WS.Activate
                    WS.Select
                    WS.Name = (WS.Name & "_" & Counter)
                    WS.Activate
                    WS.Select
                    WS.Copy After:=Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls").Sheets(i)
                    i = i + 1
                Next
                wbSource.Close False
            End If
            rst.MoveNext
        Wend
End If
```

---

I wrote the `Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls")` as it threw the same error up even more often when i used the `with` so now it looks like this;

```
If Not UserForm1.filePath = "" Then
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = OpenDatabase(UserForm1.filePath)
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tIO")
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    While Not rst.EOF
        If Not Filename = rst!Filename Then
            Filename = rst!Filename
            Dim wbSource As Workbook
            If Dir(Filename) <> "" Then
                Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filename)
                Counter = Counter + 1
                'Loop through all of the worksheets in the Active workbook
                For j = 1 To wbSource.Worksheets.Count
                    wbSource.Sheets(j).Activate
                    wbSource.Sheets(j).Select
                    wbSource.Sheets(j).Name = (wbSource.Sheets(j).Name & "_" & Counter)
                    wbSource.Sheets(j).Activate
                    wbSource.Sheets(j).Select
                    wbSource.Sheets(j).Copy After:=Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls").Sheets(Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls").Sheets.Count)
                Next
                wbSource.Close False
            End If
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend


End If
wb.SaveAs (Module1.AppendicesFolder & "\" & UserForm1.TxtJobNumber & " " & UserForm1.TxtJobName & " Appendix3 V0.00.xls")
wb.Close

xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

It seems to only happen after i have used it more than once could it be excel not closing down properly?

Comment: Do you mean the error is on this line `WS.Copy After:=Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls").Sheets(i)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a pattern to the error you're getting, my guess is that the error stems from `Sheets(i)` not `from Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls")` since you're not choosing a specific order of choosing worksheets from `wbSource`. To be quite honest, I can't really see what may be wrong in your code, but instead of

```
For Each WS in wbSource.Worksheets
```

try

```
For j = 1 To wbSource.Worksheets.Count
```

replacing every `WS` with `Sheets(j)`. Technically speaking, this should not make much of a difference, but I have gotten rid of VBA errors many times by just making seemingly useless adjustments to my code. If you figure out the solution, please post it; I'm curious to see how you resolved the problem.

Comment: No its still appearing

Answer (score 1):

If the error is on `WS.Copy After:=Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls").Sheets(i)`, I suggest that you create a new Workbook variable.

```
Dim Wb As WorkBook
Set Wb = Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls")
```

And then you use it into your copy line :

```
WS.Copy After:=Wb.Sheets(Wb.Sheets.Count)
```

---

Or as suggested  by @Jeeped, you can simply use a `With` statement :

```
With Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls")
    If Not UserForm1.filePath = "" Then
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Set db = OpenDatabase(UserForm1.filePath)
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tIO")
        Dim Filename As String
        Dim WS As Worksheet
        Dim Counter As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 1
            While Not rst.EOF
                If Not Filename = rst!Filename Then
                    Filename = rst!Filename
                    Dim wbSource As Workbook
                    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filename)

                    Counter = Counter + 1
                    'Loop through all of the worksheets in the Active workbook
                    For Each WS In wbSource.Worksheets
                        WS.Activate
                        WS.Select
                        WS.Name = (WS.Name & "_" & Counter)
                        WS.Activate
                        WS.Select
                        WS.Copy After:= .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
                        i = i + 1
                    Next
                    wbSource.Close False
                End If
                rst.MoveNext
            Wend
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Maybe a `With Workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls")` could avoid setting a new var while accomplishing the same thing...? `WS` is independent of any parent reference.

Comment: @Jeeped : Thx for suggestion, and indeed it is not necessary to use a variable, but it is a question of habits *(I generally prefer to define all variables at the start of the code to let all the "hard-coded" parameter in one place)*

Comment: I had already set wb = workbooks("Appendix 3 V0_00.xls") . Stupidly I forgot to insert it.

Comment: The with worked but when i tried using wb.sheets(wb.sheets.count) didn't i think it was because further up to the code i have:
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

Dim wb as Excel.Workbook
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("L:\SI\Appendix 3 V0_00.xls")